# sine wave that slowly ramps up frequency from f1 to f2 for a given time

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math, waveform

I'm writing a c program to generate a sinusoidal wave that slowly ramps up frequency from f1 to f2 for a giving time interval.

I have written this c program to ramp the frequency from 0 to 10 Hz but the problem is that the frequency changes after completion of 360 degrees. If I try to change the frequency between 0 and 360 degree that the transition is not smooth and it is abrupt.

This is the equation the sin that I have used y = Amplitude*sin(freq*phase)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

double y, freq,phase;
int count; // for convenience of plotting in matlab so all the waves are spread on x axis.
  for (freq = 0; freq < 10; freq+=1) {
      for (phase = 0; phase < 360; phase++) { // phase is 360 degrees
      y = 3 * sin((count*6.283185)+(freq*(phase*(3.14159/180))));   
    printf("%f %f %f \n", freq, phase, y);
   }
  count++;
  }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1. How do I change frequency smoothly for a given time period?
2. should I be looking into Fourier transformations?

Comment: To generate a "real" sin wave frequency of desired Hz use counters and timers. Using sin formula the frequency generated depends on the speed at which the program executes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you want angular frequency (w=2 pi f) to vary linearly with time then `dw/dt = a` and `w = w0 + (wn-w0)*t/tn` (where `t` goes from 0 to `tn`, `w` goes from `w0` to `wn`).  phase is the integral of that, so `phase = w0 t + (wn-w0)*t^2/(2tn)` (as oli says):

```
void sweep(double f_start, double f_end, double interval, int n_steps) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n_steps; ++i) {
        double delta = i / (float)n_steps;
        double t = interval * delta;
        double phase = 2 * PI * t * (f_start + (f_end - f_start) * delta / 2);
        while (phase > 2 * PI) phase -= 2 * PI; // optional
        printf("%f %f %f", t, phase * 180 / PI, 3 * sin(phase));
    }
}
```

(where interval is tn and delta is t/tn).

here's the output for the equivalent python code (1-10Hz over 5 seconds):

[image: 1-10 Hz over 5 seconds]

```
from math import pi, sin

def sweep(f_start, f_end, interval, n_steps):
    for i in range(n_steps):
        delta = i / float(n_steps)
        t = interval * delta
        phase = 2 * pi * t * (f_start + (f_end - f_start) * delta / 2)
        print t, phase * 180 / pi, 3 * sin(phase)

sweep(1, 10, 5, 1000)
```

ps incidentally, if you're listening to this (or looking at it - anything that involves human perception) i suspect you don't want a linear increase, but an exponential one.  but that's [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771328/sine-wave-that-logarithmically-changes-between-frequencies-f1-and-f2-at-given-ti/19777462#19777462)...

Comment: fantastic!! It worked great. 
when n_step is very large the phase -= 2 * PI is almost zero therefore sin(0) is 0. phase -= 2 * PI causes the sin wave start with negative values. The above graph is correct when while loop is commented out.Can you point me to the source where you read about this. I was loosing my hair on this for couple of days and you saved me.Thank you very much. I read about exponential increase but couldn't understand may ask you to explain intuitively.

Comment: fixed the (float) issue in the c code, thanks.  don't understand the comment about phase, but it's only there in case you want it always to be in range 0-2PI. i didn't read this anywhere - i just worked it out - but as far as i can tell, it's the same as the wikipedia entry (which i oli linked to and i checked later).

Comment: also, instead of repeated subtraction, you could do a more direct calculation.  something like `int n = phase / (2 * PI); phase -= n * 2 * PI`.

Comment: @andrew cooke you are correct, I miss understood the while loop. alternative way to implement the while loop is 'phase = fmod(phase, (2 * PI));'

Comment: yup (wasn't sure if fmod existed tbh).

Comment: @andrewcooke - "*... an exponential one. but that's a different question,*"  [which question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771328/sine-wave-that-logarithmically-changes-between-f1-and-f2-at-given-time-amount-of) has now been raised.

Answer (score 9):

> How do I change frequency smoothly for a given time period?

A smooth sinusoid requires continuous phase.  Phase is the integral of frequency, so if you have a linear function for frequency (i.e. a constant-rate increase from f1 to f2), then phase will be a quadratic function of time.

You can figure out the maths with pen and paper, or I can tell you that the resulting waveform is called a [*linear chirp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp).

> Should I be looking into Fourier transformations?

The Fourier transform of a linear chirp is itself a linear chirp, so probably no.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fairly simple.  Rather than thinking of varying the frequency, think of making an object spin faster and faster.  The angular distance it has traveled might be X after N seconds, but will be more that 2X (maybe 4X) after 2N seconds.  So come up with a formula for the angular distance (eg, alpha = k1 * T + k2 * T**2) and take the sine of that angular distance to find the value of the waveform at any time T.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (void) appendChirp:(int[])sampleData size:(int)len 
    withStartFrequency:(double)startFreq withEndFrequency:(double)endFreq 
    withGain:(double)gain {

double sampleRate = 44100.0;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    double progress = (double)i / (double)len;
    double frequency = startFreq + (progress * (endFreq - startFreq));
    double waveLength = 1.0 / frequency;

    double timePos = (double)i / sampleRate; 
    double pos = timePos / waveLength;
    double val = sin(pos * 2.0 * M_PI); // -1 to +1 

    sampleData[i] += (int)(val * 32767.0 * gain);
}

}
```

Comment: Not quite. Although this is smooth and would "look good" on a graphing calculator, a quick demonstration is enough to illustrate the error. Using this code to generate a sound surrounded by the start and end frequency sounds shows that it doesn't end in the right place. Sine(startFreq, 1 second), sweep(startFreq, endFreq, 1 second), Sine(endFreq, 1 second), then, if you like, perform some spectral analysis. My spectral analysis (Cool Edit Pro 2) shows that it goes up to 650 hertz or so.

Comment: What were your inputs when your spectral analysis showed 650 hertz? My function may not be accurate, but I'm pretty sure its output is dependent upon its input. This method came from my software synthesizer, by the way, and it sounds good as well as looks good.

Comment: @MusicGenesis I'm sorry, I forgot to tell you the parameters! I did a sine sweep from 220 to 440 hz. As I said, the sweep ends around 650 hz before the 440 sine plays.