# Weird glitch when creating sine audio signal

Tags: c#, audio, wave, trigonometry

I had a look at the wave format today and created a little wave generator. I create a sine sound like this:

```
 public static Wave GetSine(double length, double hz)
    {
        int bitRate = 44100;
        int l = (int)(bitRate * length);
        double f = 1.0 / bitRate;
        Int16[] data = new Int16[l];
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (Int16)(Math.Sin(hz * i * f * Math.PI * 2) * Int16.MaxValue);
        }
        return new Wave(false, Wave.MakeInt16WaveData(data));
    }
```

MakeInt16WaveData looks like this:

```
public static byte[] MakeInt16WaveData(Int16[] ints)
    {
        int s = sizeof(Int16);
        byte[] buf = new byte[s * ints.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(ints[i]), 0, buf, i * s, s);
        }
        return buf;
    }
```

This works as expected! Now I wanted to swoop from one frequency to another like this:

```
public static Wave GetSineSwoop(double length, double hzStart, double hzEnd)
    {
        int bitRate = 44100;
        int l = (int)(bitRate * length);
        double f = 1.0 / bitRate;
        Int16[] data = new Int16[l];
        double hz;
        double hzDelta = hzEnd - hzStart;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            hz = hzStart + ((double)i / l) * hzDelta * 0.5; // why *0.5 ?
            data[i] = (Int16)(Math.Sin(hz * i * f * Math.PI * 2) * Int16.MaxValue);
        }
        return new Wave(false, Wave.MakeInt16WaveData(data));
    }
```

Now, when I swooped from 200 to 100 Hz, the sound played from 200 to 0 hertz. For some reason I had to multiply the delta by 0.5 to get the correct output. What might be the issue here ? Is this an audio thing or is there a bug in my code ?

Thanks

**Edit by TaW:** I take the liberty to add screenshots of the data in a chart which illustrate the problem, the first is with the 0.5 factor, the 2nd with 1.0 and the 3rd & 4th with 2.0 and 5.0:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit: here is an example, a swoop from 200 to 100 hz:
Debug values:
[image: Debug values]
Wave clearly does not end at 100 hz
[image: The resulting sine wave clearly does not end at 100 hz]

Comment: What do you mean by "the sound played from 200 to 0 hertz"? Does this mean you watched the value of hz through the loop and at some point it became zero? Also, what `length` are you using? multiplying hzDelta by 0.5 would make hz go from 200 to 150.

Comment: @pixartist: I don't have an explanation, but maybe the illustrations can help somebody else to see the problem.. (Feel free to delete if you mind my edit..!)

Comment: Thanks TaW. @Jaket, no, the value behaves as expected, it ends a hzEnd. Still the played sound ends at hzStart + hzDelta*2. I'm really confused!

Comment: I added two more images to illustrate the problem. It seems the sine ends at ~4 hz (might be 0 though...)

Comment: I have added another image with a factor of 2.0. May be a hint, even if I don't get it..

Comment: Your comment about needing to multiply the delta by 0.5 to get the correct range of Hz is not correct.  Check your last Hz value, it's just over 150, not 100.

Comment: What ? Where ? In the debug window it's 100.00075...

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199509/sine-wave-that-slowly-ramps-up-frequency-from-f1-to-f2-for-a-given-time

Comment: @Doug: just when I figured it out myself.. Thanks for the interesting link anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging out my rusty math I think it may be because:

Going in L steps from frequency F1 to F2 you have a frequency of

```
Fi = F1 + i * ( F2 - F1 ) / L
```

or with

```
( F2 - F1 ) / L = S

Fi = F1 + i * S
```

Now to find out how far we have progressed we need the integral over `i`, which would be

```
I(Fi) = i * F1 + 1/2 * i ^ 2 * S
```

Which give or take resembles the term inside your formula for the `sine`.

Note that you can gain efficiency by moving the constant part (`S/2`) out of the loop..