# concatenate sinusoids of varying frequency

Tags: python, audio, concatenation, trigonometry

It's my first time working with audio and I'm trying to concatenate sinusoids of arbitrary (data-driven) frequencies, and can't get rid of the clicking noises caused by discontinuities in between the sins.

I was reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199509/sine-wave-that-slowly-ramps-up-frequency-from-f1-to-f2-for-a-given-time) on making frequency a function of phase in order to increase the frequency of a wave linearly, but couldn't figure out how to adapt this for arbitrarily shifting frequencies.

I was playing around with calculating the phase shift from the previous sinusoid, and then trying to shift the next one accordingly, but this just seemed to make the sound more high pitched and didn't remove the clicking.

```
def audio_map(data):
p=[]
phase = 0 
for point in data: 
    if point[0]<0: 
        f=100*np.abs(point[0])
    else:
        f=100*point[0]
#Do something with the phase to shift the sinusoid below??? 
p=np.concatenate((p,np.sin((4*np.pi*f/sampling_rate)*np.arange(sampling_rate*np.pi/(16)))))
    phase=f*np.pi/16

return p
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I'm also a little confused by your choice of sine function, it doesn't look like the coefficients or duration are tied to real-world values, I would expect to see something like this:

```
p = np.concatenate((p, np.sin((2 * np.pi * f / sampling_rate) * np.arange(total_tone_time * sampling_rate) + phase)))
phase += 2 * np.pi * f * total_tone_time
phase %= 2 * np.pi  # strip off full cycles to avoid overflow
```

Where

- total_tone_time is the duration of the current tone being played
- sampling_rate is measured in hz (samples per second)

The purpose of adding in the phase between each term is to keep the resultant composite curve continuous, which might help avoid any pops in the waveform.  If you can't hear anything, be sure the frequencies being output are in the audible range: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_frequency

I would try the above suggestion first before trying what I talk about below, which go much deeper down the rabbit hole.

**/EDIT**

Not an expert, but I think what you say about the discontinuity causing clicking could be correct.  If it is, you could do a fast fade out/fade in of amplitude at the junction to avoid the click.

Here are some other possibilities I can think of.

**Model and Fit**

How are you sampling the frequencies?  Are they sampled at specific times, so you can get frequency as a function of time?  If so, you could try to fit a curve to the points (which is a non-trivial problem), then take the sine of the integral of the calculated curve:

Sin[2 * PI * Integral[freq(time), time, 0, current_time]]

**Numerical Integration**

As an alternative to fitting a curve, if your frequency sampling rate is fast enough to approximate a smooth curve, you can use the values directly in a numeric integral.  For the below example I'm assuming your data is in the format of [[freq0, time0], [freq1, time1], ...] and that the frequency samples are evenly spaced over time at the same rate you'd like to sample your output waveform.

```
PI = 3.14159
waveform = [0] * len(data)
phase = 0
time_delta = data[1][1] - data[0][1]
for i, (f, t) in enumerate(data):
    if i != 0:
        phase += 0.5 * (f + last_f) * time_delta
        waveform[i] = sin(2 * PI * phase)
    last_f = f
    phase %= 2 * PI
```

Note that for the above I'm using the trapezoidal method, described here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html#bua4lsr

The one thing that concerns me about this method is that you are taking the absolute value of frequencies, which suggests to me that your frequencies may not be sampled from a data source yielding a well-behaved, continuous function.

**Add a Ramp**

Finally, if you are concatenating frequencies from a random sample with no direct time dependency, you could add a frequency ramp to bridge the gap.

You could try linear:

```
sin(PI * [(f2 - f1) / time_frame * t ** 2 + 2 * f1 * t])
```

Or exponential:

```
sin(2 * PI * time_frame * f1 * exp(log(f2 / f1) * t / time_frame) / log(f2 / f1))
```

Where

- time_frame is the duration you want the ramp to last
- t is chosen to start at zero and end at time_frame
- f1 is the frequency being left
- f2 is the frequency being entered

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough answer!! I learned a lot from your post.  For any others reading this, after a day of playing around I finally realized I could just ensure that my concatenations take place at the zero-crossings, (ie/that an integer multiple of periods are concatenated for each sinuosoid) but everything above from Meridius will prove useful in later iterations of my work. [e.g. I used something like p=np.concatenate((p,np.sin(((4*np.pi*f/sampling_rate))*np.arange(50*sampling_rate/(4*f))))) ]