# calculate multiple sine sweeps one after another

Tags: python, audio, signals, trigonometry

I'm writing a Python program to generate multiple sine sweeps one after another with varying starting and ending frequencies and varying time intervals.

One example would be:

1. sweep from 0Hz to 170Hz in 1 millisecond
2. sweep from 170Hz to 170Hz in 1 millisecond
3. sweep from 170Hz down to 10Hz in 1 millisecond

*So it is supposed to be a ramp up, ramp down waveform*.

The equation that I´ve used was inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199509/sine-wave-that-slowly-ramps-up-frequency-from-f1-to-f2-for-a-given-time)

```
def LinearSineSweep(self, fStart, fEnd, samplingTime, samplesPerSecond):
    nValues = int(samplesPerSecond * samplingTime)
    for i in range(0, nValues):
        delta = float(i) / nValues
        t = samplingTime * delta
        phase = 2 * math.pi * t * (fStart + (fEnd - fStart) * delta / 2)
        return self._amplitude * math.sin(phase) + self._dcOffset

LinearSineSweep(0, 170, 0.001, 44100)
LinearSineSweep(170, 170, 0.001, 44100)
LinearSineSweep(170, 10, 0.001, 44100)
```

But what I´m getting as an output is not correct:
[image: 170]

Even with 10 times the frequency is still doesn`t come together as one waveform

[image: 1700 HZ]

*Is this a mathematical problem or a programming problem?*

Comment: FYI: scipy provides the function `chirp` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html), which can do this (and a lot more).

Comment: Yes, I thought about this, but chirp returns an array and my datasets are much too big for an array to handle

Comment: You need a way of carrying the phase from one call to the next. You can see in your graphs that the phase is reset to zero every millisecond.

Comment: Could you check the indentation of the code in the question?  You have your `return` statement inside the loop.

Comment: As @jaket says, you must provide a way for the phase at the end of one segment to be used as the starting phase of the next segment. That's what the `phi` argument of the `scipy.signal.chirp` provides.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser. I was going to ask the same thing. I don't know python very well and assumed it might be some kind of iterator thingy. I was going to write an answer but didn't know how I might also return a tuple with the final phase in that style.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser you are right, the return statement is only at the end of the function not in the loop. There is some more Code which deals with writing it into .WAV files that I left out. The return value was only meant to be a checkback for me.
I will try the solution with the added phase as you suggested next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jaket pointed out in a comment, you must make the phase vary continuously from segment to segment (I'm paraphrasing a bit).  Here's a variation of your code that shows one way you could do this.  I don't have all your other code, so instead of `self`, the first argument of `LinearSineSweep` is a file to which the samples are written as text.  (I've also tweaked the code to compensate for the fact that the requested interval will not, in general, be an exact multiple of the sampling period.)  `numpy` are `matplotlib` are used to create the plot.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import math


def LinearSineSweep(f, fStart, fEnd, samplingTime, samplesPerSecond,
                    t0=0, phi0=0):
    nValues = int(samplesPerSecond * samplingTime)
    actualSamplingTime = nValues / samplesPerSecond
    for i in range(0, nValues):
        delta = float(i) / nValues
        t = actualSamplingTime * delta
        phase = 2 * math.pi * t * (fStart + (fEnd - fStart) * delta / 2)
        value = math.sin(phase + phi0)
        # Write the time and sample value to the output...
        print(t0 + t, value, file=f)
    phase = 2 * math.pi * actualSamplingTime * (fStart + (fEnd - fStart) / 2)
    return t0 + actualSamplingTime, phi0 + phase


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
        t, phi = LinearSineSweep(f, 0, 1700, 0.001, 44100)
        t, phi = LinearSineSweep(f, 1700, 1700, 0.001, 44100, t, phi)
        t, phi = LinearSineSweep(f, 1700, 100, 0.001, 44100, t, phi)

    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    tvals, v = np.loadtxt('out.csv', unpack=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
    plt.plot(tvals, v)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

Here's the plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: That was it, I saved the last phase, but forgot to add it together after each segment of the waveform.
Great answer!